# Is there a basic solution to the following inequality: $\log _x\left(3\right)<\log _{x+2}\left(9\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am looking for a simple solution to this inequality:

> $\log _x\left(3\right)<\log _{x+2}\left(9\right)$

I can solve it by switching to base 3, and move sides to get:
$\frac{\log \:_3\left(\frac{x+2}{x^2}\right)}{\log _3\left(x\right)\cdot \log _3\left(x+2\right)} < 0$ 
and then take all cases where odd number of elements (out of the 3 logs) is negative.

But I wonder. Is there a solution without so many cases? i.e. just by basic log rules or with just two cases?

Thaks

Comment: Do you know the change of base rule? Can you write out your steps to get that equation?

Comment: Hint: Use $log_a x = 1/log_x a$ on both sides and $(log_x a) = (log_b a) / (log_b x)$

Comment: I know the base rule of course... but its an inequality, I cant switch sides with multiplication... so 1/log_3(x)<2/log_(3)(x+2) does not give me a simple solution. it gives what I wrote above which is a solution but not the simple one I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the chance of base rule which says $ \log_a b = \frac{ \log_{c} a } { \log_{c} b }$.

With that, your inequality becomes 
$ \frac{ \log 3 } { \log x } < \frac { \log 9 } { \log (x+2)} $
$ \Leftrightarrow \log^2 (x+2) \log x < 2 \log (x+2) \log^2 x $
$ \Leftrightarrow \log (x+2) \times  \log x \times ( 2 \log x  - \log(x+2)) > 0 $.

By checking the zeros, this has solution set $  0 < x < 1  \cup 2 < x $.

Comment: I dont understand, you switched to base 10? and divided by log base 10 of 3? If yes, where is the denominator logx*log(x+2)?

Comment: Alright, I've added details.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\log_x3<\log_{x+2}3^2,$$ or $$\frac{2}{\log_3x}<\frac{1}{\log_3(x+2)}.$$

Now we only need consider the two cases $0<x<1$ and $x>1$ to proceed. For the last case, when both sides are positive, we obtain $$\log_3(x+2)^2<\log_3x,$$ from where you should be able to proceed. For the first case, when LHS is negative and RHS positive, we obtain $$\log_3x<\log_3(x+2)^2.$$ Again you should be able to proceed.

PS. You should see that the second case gives no solution, whereas the first is satisfied for all valid $x,$ that is $0<x<1.$

Comment: Side note: For inequalities (esp in logarithms), when the signage is unknown, it's often better to multiply by the square of the denominator, then factor it. That avoids having to consider numerous cases until the very end.

Comment: @CalvinLin That's true. It didn't occur to me at as when I was doing this. I just thought analysing two cases wasn't too onerous.